# Ubuntu Server 8080 is redirecting to /var/www

Tags: server, apache2, xampp

I have an `ip` and i changed the `/etc/hosts` and added `listen 8080` which is basically redirecting to `/var/www` i want to redirect that to `/var/www/html/project`.

How can i do that ?

I have searched google but nothing i got.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx? Both of them have configurations to allow you to point different ports or subdomains to different locations.

Comment: You need to specify the `DocumentRoot` in your webserver. You're alas too vague on what exactly you're doing and what you have configured.